# Creating custom Button in Swift with Visual Layout Constraints

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

```
    //signup button
    let signupButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    signupButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    signupButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "signupButton"), forState: .Normal)
    signupButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    signupButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), forState: .Normal)
    signupButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Sign Up", comment: ""), forState: .Normal)
    // align SignupButton from the top and bottom
    signupButton.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-464.5-[SignupButton]-142.5-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["signupButton": signupButton]))

    // align SignupButton from the left and right
    signupButton.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-196-[SignupButton]-30-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["signupButton": signupButton]))
    self.view.addSubview(signupButton)
```

This is what I have, and the button is created when I comment out the constraints, but the constraints are what I need to place these in the correct positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `signupButton` as a subview before adding the constraints, and the constraints should be added to the view that contains `signupButton`, which is `self.view` in this case.  Also, the key in your views dictionary is `signupButton` (starting with lowercase), but in your format string you are using `SignupButton` (starting with uppercase).

```
let signupButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
signupButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
signupButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "signupButton"), forState: .Normal)
signupButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
signupButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), forState: .Normal)
signupButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Sign Up", comment: ""), forState: .Normal)

self.view.addSubview(signupButton)

self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-464.5-[signupButton]-142.5-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["signupButton": signupButton]))
self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-196-[signupButton]-30-|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["signupButton": signupButton]))
```